# Not able to parse query parameters with # url

Tags: java, url, urlencode

Not able to parse query string parameters of url having #.

```
http://www.example.com/txn/#/user/399AC2F1BB3241823B5E48205C0657FC?utm_source=campaign&utm_medium=testmedium&page=user
```

URLEncodedUtils.parse return zero result.

Even URL.getQuery() gives null.

Any method to parse it with explicitly removing # from url.

Answer (score 3):

Everything after `#` is a *fragment*.

A URL is built like this (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)):

```
scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]
```

Your URL decomposes to (using [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), *scheme* is called *protocol* and *fragment* is called *ref*):

```
scheme   = http
host     = www.example.com
path     = txn/
query    = 
fragment = /user/399AC2F1BB3241823B5E48205C0657FC?utm_source=campaign&utm_medium=testmedium&page=user
```

Also, if you enter that URL into a web browser, the *fragment* is handled by the browser and not sent to the server.

---

If you truly want a `#` as a path component, it needs to be `%` encoded:

```
http://www.example.com/txn/%23/user/399AC2F1BB3241823B5E48205C0657FC?utm_source=campaign&utm_medium=testmedium&page=user
```

That will decompose (and decode) into:

```
scheme   = http
host     = www.example.com
path     = txn/#/user/399AC2F1BB3241823B5E48205C0657FC
query    = utm_source=campaign&utm_medium=testmedium&page=user
fragment =
```

Once the query has been extracted, you can use `URLEncodedUtils.parse`. `parse` is not for the entire URL.